# Check if voted for scope - acts as votable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

The acts_as_votable gem allows you to check if a user voted for a votable model.
https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable

`user.voted_on?(@votable)`

The gem also allows you to cast votes using a scope

`user.vote(@votable), vote_scope: 'funny'`
user.vote(@votable), vote_scope: 'useful'

I was wondering how to check if a user voted on an object, but only in a specific scope.

I imagine the code to be something like

`user.voted_on? @votable, vote_scope: 'funny'`

Is this possible with this gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your example syntax is correct:

```
user.voted_on? @votable, vote_scope: 'funny'
```

The `voted_on?` and `voted_for?` methods accept :vote_scope as an option.